# How to get the mean over time value

Tags: python, mean

I have a csv file with several data rows per second and i need to get the mean data value per second. Input data (> 2000 rows) look like this:

```
11:24:13,1.518
11:24:13,1.576
11:24:13,1.529
11:24:14,1.529
11:24:14,1.576
11:24:14,1.565
11:24:14,1.553
11:24:15,1.506
11:24:15,1.482
11:24:15,1.541
11:24:15,1.576
11:24:15,1.506
...
12:00:20,1,508
```

output should look like:

```
11:24:13,1.541
11:24:14,1.555
11:24:15,1.522
...
12:00:20,1,508
```

The answer below was already very helpful, but trying get the mean over thousands of time values with pandas I get only the first and last 15 output lines:

```
time
2013-10-30 11:24:12    1.5341
2013-10-30 11:24:13    1.5658
2013-10-30 11:24:14    1.5480
2013-10-30 11:24:15    1.5517
2013-10-30 11:24:16    1.5411
2013-10-30 11:24:17    1.5247
2013-10-30 11:24:18    1.5248
2013-10-30 11:24:19    1.5082
2013-10-30 11:24:20    1.4588
2013-10-30 11:24:21    1.6187
2013-10-30 11:24:22    1.5470
2013-10-30 11:24:23    1.5211
2013-10-30 11:24:24    1.5812
2013-10-30 11:24:25    1.5457
2013-10-30 11:24:26    1.5411  
...
2013-10-30 12:00:36    1.631900
2013-10-30 12:00:37    1.671900
2013-10-30 12:00:38    1.596400
2013-10-30 12:00:39    1.616500
2013-10-30 12:00:40    1.691700
2013-10-30 12:00:41    1.720000
2013-10-30 12:00:42    1.660100
2013-10-30 12:00:43    1.530700
2013-10-30 12:00:44    1.621200
2013-10-30 12:00:45    1.643600
2013-10-30 12:00:46    1.591600
2013-10-30 12:00:47    1.562300
2013-10-30 12:00:48    1.612900
2013-10-30 12:00:49    1.589500
2013-10-30 12:00:50    1.560667
Name: value, Length: 2199, dtype: float64
```

So I am stuck again and don't know how I can get only the time values with the mean for each of the 2199 rows? So it would look like this:

```
11:24:13,1.541
11:24:14,1.555
11:24:15,1.522
...
12:00:20,1,508
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is a need to show your effort before asking a question.

Comment: ...or just wait a few moments for an enthusiastic reply.

Comment: @beroe, I could not help exercising my pandas-fu ;), otherwise @/Diego  is right.

Comment: No problem! It's a nice and useful answer. If we all waited for perfectly compliant questions, then nothing would get answered. I get most annoyed by the obvious "do my homework" with 5 answers, and that is clearly not the case here.

Comment: No, it is not my homework :). I was looking for some ideas, because I am not that familiar with python and searching the web didn't brought anything useful to solve my problem. Never heard of pandas before, so I am thankful to have a new starting point now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) was made for that. Note that I am constructing the `DataFrame` from a string which contains the data you posted. Most of the time, you'll probably work with CSV files and pandas can parse those via [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).

```
d = """
11:24:13,1.518
11:24:13,1.576
11:24:13,1.529
11:24:14,1.529
11:24:14,1.576
11:24:14,1.565
11:24:14,1.553
11:24:15,1.506
11:24:15,1.482
11:24:15,1.541
11:24:15,1.576
11:24:15,1.506
"""

import pandas as pd

# get the data in shape
csvish = map(lambda row: row.split(','), filter(lambda s: s, d.split('\n')))

df = pd.DataFrame(csvish, columns=('time', 'value'))

# convert to sensible types (read_csv can do this implicitly)
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.value = df.value.astype(float)

df.groupby('time').value.mean()
```

Outputs something like this:

```
# outputs:

# time
# 2013-10-23 11:24:13    1.54100
# 2013-10-23 11:24:14    1.55575
# 2013-10-23 11:24:15    1.52220
```

---

Footnotes:

Using `read_csv` to parse dates can be done via `parse_dates`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(d[1:]), header=None, parse_dates=[0])
```

Using the `DataFrame` constructor can be done via `np.array`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%H:%M:%S"), 
                  row[1]) for row in csvish]), columns=('time', 'value'))
```